# What are Typescript features?

Tags: typescript

I edited tag definition here on stackoverflo but it was rejected. so i want to know if i dont understand exactly what is typescript?

tag description says: 
TypeScript as a language extension adds (amongst others) the following features:

- Type annotations and compile-time type checking
- Namespaces
- Interfaces
- Enums (to define a set of named constants)
- Generics (classes, types, and functions that can work over a variety of types)
- Await (suspends the execution until an asynchronous function return promise is - fulfilled)
- Abbreviated "arrow" syntax for anonymous functions
- Optional parameters and default parameters

so how exactly add typescript async await feature and arrow functions? for me it is pure javascript (ES) syntax,

Comment: Have you read about TypeScript in the official sources yet? https://www.typescriptlang.org

Answer (score 3):

I can't say why your tag edit might have been rejected.

TypeScript added a few things on that list before JavaScript did, either innovating in that area or early-adopting things that had been [proposed](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) for JavaScript. That includes arrow functions and default parameter values.

It's true that several items on that list are now JavaScript, such as arrow functions and `class` syntax (although TypeScript's `class` handles some things differently from JavaScript's classes, and has at least one feature [automatic property initialization from constructor parameters] that is unlikely ever to become a JavaScript feature).

Other things on that list are TypeScript-only, like static typing (the main point of TypeScript), generics, and namespaces (in the TypeScript sense).